# QT installed with wrong ABI for Android smartphone, how to get the right one

Tags: android, qt, abi

I installed Qt 5.9.1, with Android x86 selected during the installation. The Qt Creator IDE automatically detects the "Android for x86"-Kit, but when I try to deploy my programme to the smartphone, Qt Creator indicates the phone has an incompatible ABI.

I looked up my phone and found that I need ABI arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a or armeabi. I installed these for the targeted Android version using the Android SDK, but how do I get Qt to use them now (or rather, how can I set them up in the Qt Creator)?

As you can tell I'm new to Qt and I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here, but I couldn't find any source to simply point out how to set up a new ABI in the Creator after I installed it.

Answer (score 0):

That data is "cached" in the .pro.user file, so the simplest way is to close your project in Qt Creator, delete that file, and reopen the project, you'll be able to choose the kits again.